# Ruby file: "ruby_executable_hooks" syntax error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, rake

I am trying to run the command **rake db:migrate** but the terminal is complaining about a possible syntax error in the file **ruby_executable_hooks**. I found this [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32186242/rake-dbmigrate-doesnt-work-after-ruby-2-2-2-to-2-2-3-upgrade-via-rvm) but did not help me to solve the problem. On the first line of the file it looks like **title = "ruby #{ARGV*" "}"** is causing the problem as the double quotes are not escaped correctly. I have tried different combinations of escaping but still no luck. So now I am not sure if the problem is **really** related to escaping issues or something else. Many thanks

Please see bellow the **ruby_executable_hooks** file

```
  title = "ruby #{ARGV*" "}"
  $0    = ARGV.shift
  Process.setproctitle(title) if Process.methods.include?(:setproctitle)

  require 'rubygems'

  begin
    require 'executable-hooks/hooks'
    Gem::ExecutableHooks.run($0)
    rescue LoadError
    warn "unable to load executable-hooks/hooks" if ENV.key?
   ('ExecutableHooks_DEBUG')
  end

  eval File.read($0), binding, $0
```

Error message:

```
 /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval':
 /Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/bin/rake:4: syntax error, unexpected
 tSTRING_BEG, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '(' (SyntaxError)
 exec "$bindir/ruby" -x "$0" "$@"
                    ^
 from /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in
 `<main>'
```

Comment: I can’t get what did you try to express by `title = "ruby #{ARGV*" "}"`, but you are trying to multiply `Array` instance by `String` instance. What do you expect to get?

Comment: I am not trying to multiply anything + I did not write this file. Its a gem file and the above is its default configuration.

Comment: Look in .rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/bin you can see what the file looks like.

Comment: Did you upgrade to 2.2.3 using RVM?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found the solution for this problem

```
1 - delete the rake version from your system
2 - bundle install rake
3 - rake db:drop:all
4 - rake db:create:all
5 - rake db:migrate
```

For some reason when I first used the command rake db:migrate it corrupted the ruby_executable_hooks file (no idea why). Hope this will help somebody.

Comment: Shouldn't 2 be `gem install rake` ?

Answer (score 7):

`$ gem install rake`

worked for me. Didn't need to delete anything. Confusing it is, but try that before the time consuming rvm reinstalls others are proposing.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same problem and tried Eduardo's solution to no avail. What worked for me was simply uninstalling the ruby version I had (`rvm uninstall 2.2.3`) and installing it afresh again. Notice that I did not touch the database at all.

Comment: I did a gem uninstall rake, it said it's a default gem and can't be deleted. Then I wrote gem install rake and my rake was fixed.

Comment: Interesting. I couldn't uninstall nor install rake. So, I reset my ruby installation and that worked.